# Create Dynamically-named Workseet and Move entire rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Long-time user of this forum, first request for VBA help. Still consider myself a very beginner in VBA.

I need to make a daily batch file more meaningful by breaking up the rows in a single worksheet- "Main" (between 13,000 - 1,000,000 rows) into new worksheets. As this file gets processed daily, my requirement is that we can move rows based on the "Record Type" cell in column A.

The "Record Type" e.g. "25" or "41" or "ZA" could each have 3 populated columns, whilst Record Type "26" could have 30 populated... hence important to have entire row moved.

I am limited in my abilities and knowledge here, and have researched many examples on how to move rows (or a range of cells within a row) but these are limited to static options such as YES/NO, PAID/NOT PAID.

So in summary I need to: 
 1. Create a new worksheet for each distinct record in column A ("Record Type" in "Main")
 2. Move entire row from "Main" to subsequently created worksheet in row 2.

Here is my attempt that somewhat creates the new worksheets (though I have to disable the error-handling and can't run as a script- have to step-through)

```
Sub breakout1()

Workbooks(1).Activate

Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim SheetNameArray
Dim fn As WorksheetFunction
Dim CalcSetting As Integer
Dim newsht As Worksheet

Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction

With Application
CalcSetting = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
Set rng = .UsedRange
Set Rng1 = Intersect(rng, .Range("A:A"))
lastCol = rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1

.Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, lastCol + 2), Unique:=True

Set Rng2 = Intersect(.Columns(lastCol + 2).CurrentRegion, _
.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count))

ReDim SheetNameArray(1 To Rng2.Cells.Count)
SheetNameArray = fn.Transpose(Rng2)
.Columns(lastCol + 2).Clear

For x = LBound(SheetNameArray) To UBound(SheetNameArray)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(SheetNameArray(x)))
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Worksheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(SheetNameArray(x))
            Err.Clear
        End If
    'On Error GoTo 0
      'rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SheetNameArray(x)
      'Set Rng3 = Intersect(rng, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
      'Rng3.Copy Workbooks(1).Sheets(CStr(SheetNameArray(x))).Range("A1")
      'rng.AutoFilter
 Next x
End With
Range("A1").Select
Application.Calculation = CalcSetting

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't focus on your true goal which I couldn't grasp out of your description

but here's a refactoring of your code that works for creating and/or populating sheets named after what found in unique values in "base" sheet (se code to set it properly) column "A

```
Option Explicit

Sub breakout2()

Dim x As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim SheetNameArray As Variant
Dim CalcSetting As Integer
Dim newsht As Worksheet, BaseSht As Worksheet

With Application
    CalcSetting = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set BaseSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("breakout") '<== choose "base" sheet
'Set BaseSht= Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet '<== this would activate the first workbook opend in current excel session. is it the one you actually want?

With BaseSht
    Set rng = .UsedRange
    SheetNameArray = GetSheetNames(rng, 1, 2)

    For x = LBound(SheetNameArray) To UBound(SheetNameArray)
        Set newsht = SetSheet(CStr(SheetNameArray(x)))

        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SheetNameArray(x)
        Intersect(rng, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy Parent.Sheets(CStr(SheetNameArray(x))).Range("A1")
        rng.AutoFilter
    Next x
End With

Range("A1").Select '<=== what for? Selection is rarely a good programming habit. set and use 'range' type variables instead

With Application
    .Calculation = CalcSetting
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub


Function SetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName).Activate
If Err <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = shtName
End If
Set SetSheet = ActiveSheet

End Function


Function GetSheetNames(usedRng As Range, colWithSheetNames As Long, colShift As Long) As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rangeToScan As Range, rangeWithNames As Range, rngToCopyTo As Range

With usedRng
    Set sht = .Parent
    Set rngToCopyTo = sht.Columns(.Columns(.Columns.Count).column + 2)
End With

With sht
    Set rangeToScan = Intersect(usedRng, .Columns(colWithSheetNames))
    rangeToScan.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rngToCopyTo, Unique:=True
    Set rangeWithNames = .Range(rngToCopyTo.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngToCopyTo.column).End(xlUp))
End With

GetSheetNames = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rangeWithNames)
rngToCopyTo.Clear

End Function
```

Comment: Dearest @user3598756, thank you kindly! Pardon the poor explanation- should have kept it simple- You have understood correctly!

Why would I get this error when running sub breakout2:

_"Run-time error '1004': We couldn't do this for the selected range of cells. Select a single cell within a range of data and then try again.'_

When I click 'Debug' in the VB pop-up, it highlights an issue with:

`rangeToScan.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rngToCopyTo, Unique:=True`

Comment: Further to my previous comment when I name my worksheet "Sheet1" it errors as per previous comment, but if I rename the sheet as anything else such as "Main" or "Breakout" it throws the error _Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range_ and stops at `Set BaseSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")`.
Your assistance is invaluable!

Comment: as for the 1004 error: give details about: "rangeToScan"  and "CopyToRange" address property values when you hit the error.   as for the "Sheet1" issue give details about workbook name that contains the Macro, workbook name that contains the "base" sheet, "base" sheet name.   the best would be you uploaded the workbooks involved